# Struggling with a data modeling problem

Tags: datamodel, database-design

I am struggling with a data model (I use MySQL for the database).  I am uneasy about what I have come up with.  If someone could suggest a better approach, or point me to some reference matter I would appreciate it.

The data would have organizations of many types.  I am trying to do a 3 level classification (Class, Category, Type).  Say if I have 'Italian Restaurant', it will have the following classification

Food Services > Restaurants > Italian

However, an organization may belong to multiple groups.  A restaurant may also serve Chinese and Italian.  So it will fit into 2 classifications

Food Services > Restaurants > Italian
Food Services > Restaurants > Chinese

The classification reference tables would be like the following:

**ORG_CLASS (RowId, ClassCode, ClassName)**

```
1, FOOD, Food Services
```

**ORG_CATEGORY(RowId, ClassCode, CategoryCode, CategoryName)**

```
1, FOOD, REST, Restaurants
```

**ORG_TYPE (RowId, ClassCode, CategoryCode, TypeCode, TypeName)**

```
100, FOOD, REST, ITAL, Italian
101, FOOD, REST, CHIN, Chinese
102, FOOD, REST, SPAN, Spanish
103, FOOD, REST, MEXI, Mexican
104, FOOD, REST, FREN, French
105, FOOD, REST, MIDL, Middle Eastern
```

The actual data tables would be like the following:

I will allow an organization a max of 3 classifications.  I will have 3 GroupIds each pointing to a row in ORG_TYPE. So I have my ORGANIZATION_TABLE

**ORGANIZATION_TABLE (OrgGroupId1, OrgGroupId2, OrgGroupId3, OrgName, OrgAddres)**

```
100,103,NULL,MyRestaurant1, MyAddr1
100,102,NULL,MyRestaurant2, MyAddr2
100,104,105, MyRestaurant3, MyAddr3
```

During data add, a dialog could let the user choose the clssa, category, type and the corresponding GroupId could be populated with the rowid from the ORG_TYPE table.

During Search, If all three classification are chosen, It will be more specific.  For example, if

Food Services > Restaurants > Italian is the criteria, the where clause would be `'where OrgGroupId1 = 100'`

If only 2 levels are chosen

Food Services > Restaurants

I have to do `'where OrgGroupId1 in (100,101,102,103,104,105, .....)'` - There could be a hundred in that list

I will disallow class level search.  That is I will force selection of a class and category

The Ids would be integers.  I am trying to see performance issues and other issues.

Overall, would this work? or I need to throw this out and start from scratch.

Comment: this might be overkill for your purposes, but a good article about managing hierachical Data: http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/hierarchical-data.html

Comment: Thanks for the link.  It indeed is a good reference.  It did let me have another option for the classification.  This approach in the article is more flexible and does not limit the number levels of classification.

Comment: @trickwallet: The article is not available anymore at this address. It is now here: http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

Comment: I actually ended up with a data mode along the lines of what is recommended in the article for a hierarchical data structure.  It is my hope that this article is available as a reference for anyone wanting to set up a hierarchical data model.  Thanks for publishing the new location of the article.

Answer (score 1):

I don't like the having three columns for the "up to three" classifications. In my opinion it would be better to have a cross-reference table that allows your many-to-many mapping between organisation and type, i.e. table ORGANISATION_GROUPS with columns OrganisationId, OrgGroupId.

To sort out the problem of being able to query a different levels of classification specified you could setup this cross-ref table to hold the actual classifications, i.e. ORGANISATION_GROUPS instead has columnns: OrganisationId, ClassCode, CategoryCode, TypeCode.

This will make queries at different levels of classification very easy.

For referential integrity to work with this scheme I'd then suggest not using surrogate integer keys for your ORG_* tables but instead setting the primary key to be the real unique key, i.e. ClassCode, CategoryCode, TypeCode for ORG_TYPE.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Even I had felt the need for a cross-ref table.  However, I am working with existing software which works well if everything is in one table.  The application is not too complicated at the moment.  I had therefore thought of putting the classification in the data table itself.  If I have to scale up, I can perhaps move the classification out of the data table and create the cross-ref table.  I am trying to see if I can postpone major changes to the existing software.

Answer (score 0):

The problem i see in your design is that it is a bit rigid. A more flexible approach you might want to consider is following:

First you would have a table for classes, categories, types and any other classification type. This table would be auto-referenced. All registers would have a field referring to its immediate parent, like following:

**CLASSIFICATION (Id, Description, Parent_Id)**

```
ITAL, Italian, REST
CHIN, Chinese, REST
MEXI, Mexican, REST
REST, Restaurant, FOOD
```

Next you would have, as @John pickup suggested, an intermediate cross-reference table between your restaurant (or whatever you need) table and the classification table which would contain only a composite primary key, being its components the primary key of both tables.

**FOODSERVICE_CLASSIFICATION** (Rest_Id, Class_Id)

```
100, ITAL
100, CHIN
101, MEXI
102, CHIN
```

It would be advisable to limit it so that only leaf registers of the CLASSIFICATION table can be referenced in the cross-reference table.

Your example of looking for all restaurants would be as simple as looking for all child categories of REST and search for them in the cross-reference table. This can be written in a single select in Oracle (not sure about other RDBMS).

This way you can:

- have multiple categorization for your restaurants without being limited to 3 categories.
- Do quick searches using the cross-reference table.

Mind you, this schema would work supposing your categorization is like a tree with a base category acting as the root. If instead you need a more loose categorization you would probably need a tags approach.

Btw, I also agree with @John Pickup that it is better to use real primary keys in this case.

HTH

Comment: I appreciate your help.  I will try to hash out what you have suggested and see if I can come up with a model.  I may just use the hierarchy suggested.  I am working with existing software which may need to change if I am to use the cross-ref table.